# How to find the PID of a running command in cmd/powershell over SSH?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, pid

Something similar to echo $$; python my_script.py > out.log

Expected output:

using cmd_command or powershell command

Comment: for the PID use `$PID` automatic variable.

Comment: @Hazrelle, Thanks, similar stuff required for windows

Comment: You can use `Get-Process` but you need to know name of the process that display the windows.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running PowerShell, the PID variable is available.

```
PS C:\> $PID
8420
PS C:\> Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessId -eq $PID }

ProcessId Name     HandleCount WorkingSetSize VirtualSize
--------- ----     ----------- -------------- -----------
8420      pwsh.exe 1004        119939072      2204255981568
```

See the other members available using:

```
Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Process | Where-Object { $_.ProcessId -eq $PID } | Format-List -Property * -Force
```

or

```
Get-CimInstance -Class CIM_Process | Get-Member
```